# My VBA code is getting slower every iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the code to add a column, bucket the value on left (via a vlookup) and then auto fill the whole column. The problem I'm having is every time I use the macro, the code is taking slightly longer and longer. Would appreciate any help :)

Here is the code:

```
 Sub insert_col()
 '
 ' insert_col Macro
 '
 ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
 '
 Dim x As Variant
 Dim a As Long
 Dim b As Long
 Dim y As Variant
 Dim t As Single

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

t = Timer

ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveCell.Column).EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
x = ActiveCell.Column
Cells(22, x).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R13C1:R193C2,1)"
Cells(22, x).Select
a = ActiveCell.Column
x = ActiveCell.Row
y = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(x, a), Cells(36600, a)), Type:=xlFillDefault
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select

MsgBox Timer - t

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: You add a quantity of data in the sheet... Ok, are not Updated the value, but the data is added. If you delete the data the macro use the same time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clearer on the comment above, your code adds additional formulae each time it is run which increases the calculation time.

You can greater simply the code along the lines below:

```
Sub insert_col()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

t = Timer

ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
Range(Cells(22, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(36600, ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R13C1:R193C2,1)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select

MsgBox Timer - t

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```